# unit testing REST client -- mock the service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to test `REST` client functionality when the response status indicates error. So I want to mock the rest service to return an error code (like 404) and test that the client is handling the error cases correctly. Is there a way to mock the service?

Comment: I think you need to mock REST client's rest communication module, not the server module. what is your REST client's language and Rest module (or Http Client module)?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/ning/async-http-client/ to make the REST call

Answer (score 2):

Try [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

It's a nice mocking framework for Java

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Spring MVC Test Support](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

mockito is a good choice for unit testing.
If you are interested in automated integration testing you might wanna try some webservice mocking tool, such as this one:
https://sourceforge.net/p/soaprest-mocker

You can set response code and/or response body on mock, execute your request against the mock and verify request(s) that reached the mock.